# an error of opencv on python about boundingRect

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

When I try the code about motion capture,I can't run succesfully because of this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\machine learning\CV\Video Capture\motion capture with square.py", line 21, in <module>
    x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(thresh)
error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:1895: error: (-215) points.checkVector(2) >= 0 && (points.depth() == CV_32F || points.depth() == CV_32S) in function cv::boundingRect
```

Firtly, I thought maybe the data type may wrong, so I change the type to the 'float32' and 'int32'. But it can't help, so I have no idea.

And here is my code:

```
import cv2  
import numpy as np
camera=cv2.VideoCapture(0)  
firstframe=None  
while True:  
    ret,frame = camera.read()
    #cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    if not ret:  
        break  
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
    gray=cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0)  
    if firstframe is None:  
        firstframe=gray  
        continue  

    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstframe,gray)  
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]  
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)  
    #(cnts,_)= cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(thresh)  
    frame=cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)  
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)  
    cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)  
    cv2.imshow("frame2", frameDelta)  
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF  

    if key == ord("q"):  
        break  

camera.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `cv2.boundingRect()` expects a set of points `(x, y)` coordinates in a special format to calculate the bounding rect, Your input image is not a set of `(x, y)` points. This method is not meant to be applied directly onto images. You must find [contours](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) of the given binary mask, then you can iterate all the contours and call `cv2.boundingRect()` on the individual contours as:

```
cnts, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Iterate over all the contours.
for contour in cnts:
    print cv2.boundingRect(contour)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but cv2.findContours only have two feedback, which one should be deleted, and whats the contour mean, it seem like that we don't define it.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you must be using OpenCV 3.x, however I have edited the answer as per 2.7 API, and here is the documentation for [contours](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, I have handled this problem.